# How to use ContentResolver.requestSync(Account account, String authority, Bundle extras) to force immediate account syncs?

Tags: java, android, bundle, android-contentresolver

I have gotten a list of accounts on my phone using the code below, and now at the click of a button in my app I want to force them to start auto sync.

```
AccountManager account_manager=AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = account_manager.getAccounts();
```

How can I use [public static void requestSync (Account account, String authority, Bundle extras)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#requestSync%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) to force an immediate Sync?

**Question**: What to put for 'authority' and 'extras'?

Comment: Are you using SyncUtils from syncadapters? I think there is a static method TriggerRefresh() in it.You can use that for instant sync. Is that you wanted?

Comment: @playmaker420 - Yes, the TriggerRefresh helps but I want to force sync on accounts by OTHER apps (like facebook, gmail, etc.). I am able to get the accounts by these other apps in 'account' but I am unable to find how to find 'authority' for those OTHER apps???? TriggerRefresh tells me the 'extras' bundle I need to use.

Comment: http://www.afterhoursdevelopers.com/applications/android/synker-android-sync-widget .Try decomplie it and check. You might get a clue